# If base space of fiber bundle is simply connected then so is the total space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fundamental-groups, fiber-bundles

Let $F \to E \to B$ be a fiber bundle, and assume $E$ is connected and $F$ is simply connected.  If the base space $B$ is simply connected, then is the total space $E$ also simply connected?

I think this is true by the homotopy lifting property, but I am not positive.  [My apologies if this question is silly; I'm just starting to learn differential/algebraic topology.]

EDIT: Edited to include the assumption that the fiber $F$ is simply connected.

Comment: How about $1 \to S^1 \to S^1 \times S^2 \to S^2$?

Comment: Any space is a fiber bundle over a point and the point is simply connected.

Comment: Ah, good points!  What if the fiber is also simply connected?  I edited the question to account for this.

Comment: Read about the exact sequence of homotopy groups of a fiber bundle.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Got it, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @ccriscitiello Then you should write an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  As @MoisheKohan pointed out, the tool to use here is the [long exact sequence of a fiber bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group#Long_exact_sequence_of_a_fibration).  I will assume that $F$ is path-connected and simply connected ($\pi_0(F) = 1, \pi_1(F) = 1$).

In this case, we have the (short) exact sequence
$$1 = \pi_1(F) \stackrel{f}{\to} \pi_1(E) \stackrel{g}{\to} \pi_1(B) \stackrel{h}{\to} \pi_0(F) = 1$$
where $f, g, h$ are group homomorphisms.  By exactness,
$1 = im(f) = ker(g)$ (i.e., $g$ is injective) and $im(g) = ker(h) = \pi_1(B)$ (i.e., $g$ is surjective).  Therefore, $\pi_1(E) \cong \pi_1(B)$.  In particular, $B$ is simply connected if and only if $E$ is simply connected.

Comment: You can also accept your answer.